# Error while trying to install Kops on Ubuntu 20 EC2 Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I went through the steps listed here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kops/

After moving the kops file to /usr/local/bin/ and renaming to kops, I tried to confirm if it was in fact installed and executable by trying 'kops --help' and 'kops --version'/'kops version' and neither command worked. Any idea what the issue might be?

Edit: Here's what I did step by step

1. curl -LO https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/releases/download/$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kops/releases/latest | grep tag_name | cut -d '"' -f 4)/kops-darwin-amd64
2. sudo chmod +x kops-darwin-amd64
3. sudo mv kops-darwin-amd64 /usr/local/bin/kops

It's a t2.micro Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 Instance.

Tried to confirm if kops was properly installed and executable by entering 'kops --help' and 'kops --version' and also 'kops version' but they all return this error:

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/kops: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and it is unclear. Writing "neither command worked" is not specific, and does not provide ANY information of what errors or difficulties you have.

Comment: Hi @Marcin I just edited the question for more clarity. I apologize for not being clearer earlier. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: What exactly is your AMI id for the instance?

Comment: @Marcin AMI id = ami-0d5bf08bc8017c83b

Comment: Also for context, I successfully installed kubectl following the official doc as well so I figured this would be the same routine.

Comment: And the full name of the ami?

Comment: @Marcin AMI name = ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20220914

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because you are using `kops-darwin-amd64`. This is for mac. I think you should be using `kops-linux-amd64` instead for linux.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how I missed that. I guess it wasn't specified in the document and I didn't take note of the details. This worked!